# Hibernate @ManyToOne and @OneToMany with Liquibase

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, liquibase

I have been on this for serveral nights. I would like to link number in user (one user to many numbers) with user in number (many numbers to one user). I have no luck and need your knowledge. No matter what I do I always get errors with either this or that. A straight answer of what to do will do.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

**User entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Users implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2323232323L;

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
  private List<Number> number;
```

**Number entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "number")
public class Number implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1212121212L;

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Users user;
```

**Liquibase:**

```
<createTable tableName="user">
      <column name="id" type="BIGINT(8)" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
      </column>
      <column name="fk_number" type="BIGINT"/>
    </createTable>

    <createTable tableName="number">
      <column name="id" type="BIGINT(8)" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
      </column>
      <column name="user" type="BIGINT"/>
    </createTable>
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are facing ?

Comment: nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [user_id] in table [number]

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 issues you need to fix:

1. In a relational table model, you normally model a many-to-one/one-to-many association with a foreign key column on the many side. So, in your example, you only need a foreign key column on the `number` table and not on the `user` table.
2. If you don't specify a `@JoinColumn`, Hibernate expects that the name of the foreign key column follows this pattern `<name of the attribute that owns association>_<name of the primary key of referenced entity>`. In your example, Hibernate expects a `number_id` column in the `number` table. You can learn more about association mappings in my [Ultimate Guide - Association Mappings with JPA and Hibernate](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/).

It should work, if you keep your entity mappings and use this table definition:

```
<createTable tableName="user">
  <column name="id" type="BIGINT(8)" autoIncrement="true">
    <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
  </column>
</createTable>

<createTable tableName="number">
  <column name="id" type="BIGINT(8)" autoIncrement="true">
    <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
  </column>
  <column name="user_id" type="BIGINT"/>
</createTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, you will be having a foreign key in **number** table which will represent the user to whom the number will be associated.

Since you are not mentioning `@JoinColumn` (the annotatiuon which holds information about foreign key)while specifying the `@ManyToOne` relationship in your Number Entity, thus, by default jpa is trying to look for the column named **user_id** in your number table(which is not available)

Just add the annotation @JoinColumn giving proper attributes , it should work.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="<<name of foreign key in number table>>", refrencedColumnName = "id")
```

`refrencedColumnName` tells which column has to referred in the parent entity.